# grep not matching strings when they come from a variable

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm writing a script that is helping me process log files. In it, I have my grep flags stored in a variable. The flags and strings themselves work just fine, but when I pass them to grep using a variable, the parts of the string that use escaped characters don't produce any matches. See below:

```
grepvars="-B4 -Psihe 'caused\sby|unable|fault|error|deadlock|checkpoint|corrupt|fail|exception|fatal|severe|\tat\s'"
grep -B4 -Psihe 'caused\sby|unable|fault|error|deadlock|checkpoint|corrupt|fail|exception|fatal|severe|\tat\s' adapter_15.log > adapter_15-error1.log
grep $grepvars adapter_15.log > adapter_15-error2.log
wc -l *-error?.log
  51398 adapter_15-error1.log
  25032 adapter_15-error2.log
```

As you can see, the \tat\s part does not produce matches when passed through a variable to grep. What that is supposed to match is a (literal tab)at(literal space). Although this works correctly without using a variable, I'd rather use one since it makes my multiple grep calls easier to manage. What do I have to do to ensure that grep will perform this match correctly when passed through a variable?

Comment: What if you use `egrep` / `grep -E` instead?

Comment: Quotes aren't processed when expanding a variable.

Comment: it works for me , use grep -E or egrep

Comment: It would also be helpful to indicate whether you are using GNU grep or another grep, as the flags may be different than you or I expect.

Comment: I'm using the grep that comes with Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Also, the -P flag doesn't work with egrep or grep -E. I think -P is necessary to get the \t to work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not having any sort of luck with this, I found a workaround: create a function and call it when needed. Here's what I came up with:

```
grep4j () {
unset IFS
nice -n 15 grep -B3 -Psihe '\tat\s|caused\sby|unable|fault|error|deadlock|checkpoint|corrupt|fail|exception|fatal|severe' $1
IFS=$'\n'
}
```

Yes, I did try unsetting IFS before and after the grep strings that were using the varaible. It didn't work (and I need it to be set for other things to work). Doing the function like this met my needs, and maybe it will help someone else as well. Cheers!

In case you're curious, this is designed to get relevant messages out of log4j-formatted logs. It saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing all the options of grep in a string then I guess you need to use evil `eval`:

```
str="grep $grepvars adapter_15.log > adapter_15-error2.log"
eval "$str"
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses -- eval is a statement, not a function.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, you're right. My bad habits from JS, PHP coming to shell scripts I guess.

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks, while it's not the solution I chose, it pointed me in the right direction and gave me the idea to just use a function.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to stuff options into the environment variable GREP_OPTIONS, and patterns into a file, like so:

```
grep -f <file-with-patterns> ...
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid external file dependencies, but if I have to, I'll consider this.